# Read Shapefile from Google Cloud Storage using Dataflow + Beam + Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, shapefile

How can one read Shapefile from Google Cloud Storage using Dataflow + Beam + Python.
I've found only `beam.io.ReadFromText`, but python shapefile reader demands file-like object: `shp.Reader(shp=shp_file, dbf=dbf_file)` or a shapefile.
I'm using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way to do it:

```py
prj_file =  beam.io.gcp.gcsio.GcsIO().open(
    filenamePRJ, 
    mode='r',
    read_buffer_size=1677721600, 
    mime_type='application/octet-stream'
)

shp_file = beam.io.gcp.gcsio.GcsIO().open(
    filenameSHP, 
    mode='r',
    read_buffer_size=1677721600,
    mime_type='application/octet-stream'
)

dbf_file =  beam.io.gcp.gcsio.GcsIO().open(
    filenameDBF,
    mode='r',
    read_buffer_size=1677721600,
    mime_type='application/octet-stream'
)

sf = shp.Reader(shp=shp_file, dbf=dbf_file)      
euref  = osr.SpatialReference()
euref.ImportFromWkt(str(prj_file.read()))
wgs84 = osr.SpatialReference()
wgs84.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
transformation = osr.CoordinateTransformation(euref,wgs84)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is python package that includes custom Beam I/O connectors for reading Shapefiles: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataflow-geobeam